# ld_preload and memcpy, pointer written to injected program points to NOPs

Tags: c++, pointers, memcpy

So I have a function I would like to change the argument of in a program. I have disassembled it to see what arguments this function takes and I have successfully written to that argument (Which takes a pointer). The pointer I am writting into memory overwrites the pointer already there and it SHOULD point to a pre-initialized character array but when I inspect the memory closer it actually points to some random NOPs.

Here's my C++ LD_PRELOAD patch:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "hook.h"

char kick_patch[] = "Kicked";
const char* pkick_patch = kick_patch;

void new_SV_trigger()
{
    unsigned long kick_patch_p = 0x084632A9;
    printf("Kick patch string address: %X\n", &kick_patch);
    memcpy( (void*) kick_patch_p, &pkick_patch, 4);
}


void  __attribute__((constructor)) init (void)
{
    Hook h_SV_trigger( (void*) 0x081641D1, 5, (void*) new_SV_trigger );
}
```

As you can see I am writing the pointer of `kick_patch` to address `0x084632A9` when `new_SV_trigger` is triggered which works well (Still unclear why memcpy won't let me pass `&kick_patch_p` in the second argument, it always copies the content of the char array into memory and not the actual pointer to index 0, anyways).

The problem here is that when I inspect memory address `0x084632A9` all is fine, it has written the pointer of `kick_patch`'s first index which is what I need but when I inspect the memory address of `kick_patch` it's all NOPs/0x00.

I have no idea what's going on there.

Comment: You're writing to (apparently) arbitrary virtual memory addresses; why do you expect that to work?

Comment: Well what I would like to do is have a character array in memory so I can use it within the program I am injecting into.

Comment: But what are `0x084632A9` and `0x081641D1`?

Comment: Arbitrary memory addresses at which contain data I would like to rewrite in order for the program I am injecting into to execute differently. For example @ `0x084632A9 - 4` there is an operation `dword ptr [esp+4], offset aKick`, I would like to modify that operation so that `offset aKick` becomes the offset of my character array